# Recommended size for chrome extension popup

Tags: layout, overlay

What from the perspective of UX should be ideal size of chrome extension popup window for an extension which will allow users to add the visited site to their bookmark collect and then add tags or a new folder to their added bookmark

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It depends, but generally, if you don't need a pop up, don't use one.

Long answer: You need to fit a certain amount of content within a certain amount of space. Period. You want to make it easy to read (accessibility) AND look nice (aesthetics). This means that you'd use a minimum of 14px fonts, at least 20px padding/margins, and then see if you have need/reason to go larger. So, again, it depends on whether you content will fit in the window, but you can ballpark it at 600px width and 400px height. Again, it's best to design to your physical monitor screen (1) then content (2) then determine your digital window pane constraints (3) from that (rather than 132... though this isn't a rule, just a convention). Lastly, you should be clear about your own constraints (are you designing for mobile, desktop, or both?) and look up some references.